# Discrete Linear Programming over Finite Fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

$A$ is an $l\times m$ matrix with integer entries and each column of which contains at least one negative entry. $y$ is a column matrix with integer entries of length $l$. Define the set of sequence $X = \{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\text{ for some natural number }n\}$ as follows. $x_i$ is a column matrix of length $m$ with all zero but one natural number entry $\forall 1\le i\le n$ for some natural number $n$. Note different $x$'s have different $n$'s. For any $x\in X$, let $s(x):= (s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_n)$ where $s_1 := y+Ax_1$ and $s_{i+1} := s_i+Ax_{i+1}$, and the entries of $s_i$ have to be all non-negative, $\forall i\in [1,2,\cdots, n-1]$. Let $\alpha(x)$ be the cardinality of $x\in X$. In other words, $\alpha(x)$ is the index of the last element of the sequence $x$.

Given a positive integer $j$, find $x_{\text{max}}$ that maximizes the $j$'th entry of $s_{\alpha(x)}$ of $s(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

---

The original formulation of the problem is not well posed as pointed out by Hans Engler in his answer. I have now modified the formulation of the problem.

Would we solve this problem using say, integer programming, linear algebra over finite field, or group theory?

Comment: Given e.g. $(x_1, x_2)\in X$, what is $x_1$? A real number? An integer? I don't see where finite fields are involved here (especially given that $\alpha(x)$ can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: @Math1000: Please refer to the third sentence in the question which stipulates: "$x_i$ is a column matrix with all zero but one natural number entry $\forall 1\le i\le n$ for some natural number $n$."  $\alpha(x)$ can be arbitrarily large. If each column of $A$ has at least one negative integer entry, would it make finite field relevant?

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Thank you pointing out the ambiguity in the question. I have added the length of the elements of $X$ in the question. So your second statement is correct. As stated in the question $X$ is a set whose elements are sequences of vector of the same length equal to the number of columns of $A$, so that $Ax_i$ makes sense. Is question clear now?

Comment: How do you know that the entries of $s_i$ are all non-negative? This does not follow from the assumptions.

Comment: To make progress on the question itself: Suppose $\ell = m = 2$ and $A$ is the identity matrix. Pick $x_i = (1,0)^T$ for all $i$. Then $s_i = (i,0)^T$. What is $\alpha(x)$ in this case?

Comment: @HansEngler: The entries of $s_i$ are REQUIRED to be non-negative. This is part of the definition of the set $X$. In other words, this is part of the constraint. The second sentence says "Define the set ... as follows" which means what follows is the definition.

Comment: @HansEngler: Regarding your identity example, please refer to my comment below your answer. More specifically, this case leads to an answer of infinity but it is not the general case. Perhaps I can add the requirement which constitutes the most interesting case that each column of $A$ contains at least one negative integer. I was trying to make the question more general.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: If beyond certain $n$, there no more $x_i$'s to ensure $s_i$ to be negative, then $(x_i)$ terminates and $\alpha(x):=n$. That is how the cardinality $\alpha(x)$ is defined. The problem is to choose from the set $X$ of such sequence of $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\alpha(x)}$ the sequence $x_{\text{max}}$ that maximizes the $j$'th entry of $Ax_{\alpha(x)}$. I agree that the question can be formulated even more clearly. I will try to improve the formulation.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: On second thought, the description of $s_i$ is part of the definition of $X$ in the question. We only need to find all such (finite or not) sequence $(x_i)$ that ensures $s_i$ be non-negative. Does this help to make it clearer?

Comment: How are finite fields relevant to this?  (Maybe they are, I'd just like to understand how.  I've never heard of doing "linear programming over a finite field".)

Comment: @littleO: I do not know. I was just guessing as the entries of the matrices are integers. I was hoping some kind of modular arithmetic on vectors would help to compensate for the non-commutativeness of the addition in the column matrices $x_i$'s. It may well be wishful thinking.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with finite fields. Even if the calculations were done modulo a prime number it would not, because the elements of a finite field have no order relation - it is non-sensical to say that one element of a finite field would be larger or smaller than another. Consequently you cannot call such an element positive or negative either. You could try to find a maximum of a function from a cartesian power of a finite field to the reals, but that does not seem to be the case here (and such a function would not be linear anyway). Removing the tag.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Fair enough. Any ideas, thoughts for a solution? Probably it is nonsensical also, but if we ask to characterize the set of $s_{\alpha(x)}$, would finite field or group theory help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $s_j = A(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_j)$.You can make the entries of such a vector as large as you want by choosing a sufficiently large $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = \dots$ or by making $n$ sufficiently large.

Your problem is not well posed.

**More generally:** Since $s_j = A (\sum_{i \le j} x_i)$, once you have a sequence $x  \in X$ with a positive entry somewhere in $s_{\alpha(x)}$, you can just create a new sequence $y \in X$ by repeating all elements of $x$ as many times as you want, say $M$ times. Then the new $s_{\alpha(y)}$ equals $M s_{\alpha(x)}$.

Your objective function is not bounded above.

Comment: Your assertion does not hold in general. Your answer only applies when all entries of one column of $A$ are all non-negative and of which at least one entry is positive. When there is at least one entry of each column is negative, your assertion does not hold. I could have stipulated as I have done in the last sentence. But I left it unspecified so as to be more general and admit infinity as maximum as the case you have raised. But that is not the most interesting case. Would you agree?

Comment: Actually, a better and more interesting case is $A$ has one column with non-negative integer entries with at least one positive integer entry and all other columns each of which has at least one negative integer entry.

Comment: @Hans - are you trying to argue with me or are you interested getting a solution? See my edited answer above.

Comment: I am sorry if the tone of my comment offended you. I was only trying to make my case. Of course I am seeking a solution. You are correct and my formulation of the problem was wrong. I will edit my question. Thank you!

Comment: I have now modified the question. Please review. Thank you. Do you any ideas or suggestions how to solve the present problem?

Comment: I think you need to characterize under what conditions a sequence $x \in X$ is maximal, that is, it is impossible to append an additional vector. Consider $x$ as a $m \times n$ matrix and let $e_k$ be the n-dim column vector with the first $k$ entries equal to 1 and the remaining entries equal to 0,  then this occurs if  $s_n = y + Axe_n \ge 0$ componentwise and $s_n + A_j$ has at least one negative component for all columns $A_j$ of $A$. So it is not clear that there is always a maximal $n$.

Comment: We may have non-maximal $x\in X$. For example, $y=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$. But do we really need all $x\in X$ to be maximal? We just need to find one $x$ that maximizes one entry of $s_{\alpha(x)}$ for all $x\in X$, or show that that entry is unbounded from above. Do you not think so?

Comment: It will be interesting though to characterize the condition on $A$ that terminates (maximizes) any sequence $x\in X$.

Comment: A "quick and dirty" way would use a suitable greedy algorithm to generate an $x \in X$ that has as many members as possible. Then observe the $s_j$ that come from the sequence and look for a maximizer. Terminate when it looks like the process is cyclic as in your last example.

Comment: First, when there are many "paths" to "transport" the entries of $y$ to the target coordinate of $s$, it is reasonably easy to find one such path. Finding one path is I think easy and therefore not very interesting. But it is not immediately clear which or what combination of them is a better greedy algorithm.  Second, I am much more interested in the true optimal solution.

Comment: I think it will be interesting to find a --- hopefully tight --- upper bound on the length of $x_{\text{max}}$ if each $x_i$ is now a column matrix with all zero but one entry of $1$. Once that is obtained, we can turn this problem into integer linear programming.